# How to make a difficulty bar dynamic?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

I have this component called Difficulty Bar.
I want to make it dynamic according to the difficulty level(i.e for beginner only the first dot background is colored other is not and for the intermediate, only the first two dots are colored and so on...)
I am using react with tailwind CSS.
Please help me.
[image]

```
import React from 'react'

const DifficultyBar = () => {
    return (
        <div class="max-w-xl mx-4 my-2">
        <p className="pb-2 px-2 font-bold">Beginner</p> 
        <div class="flex pb-3">
            <div class="flex-1 z-10">
                <div class="w-6 h-6 bg-secondary mx-0 rounded-full border-2 border-secondary">
                </div>
            </div>
    
    
            <div class="w-full align-center items-center align-middle content-center flex">
            <div class="w-full items-center align-middle align-center flex-1">
                    <div class="bg-white border-2 -ml-2 rounded-full border-secondary py-xs w-full"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            
            <div class="flex-1 z-10">
                <div class="w-6 h-6 bg-white -ml-4 rounded-full border-2 border-secondary">
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="w-full align-center items-center align-middle content-center flex">
            <div class="w-full items-center align-middle align-center flex-1">
                     <div class="bg-white border-2 -ml-2 rounded-full border-secondary py-xs w-full"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="flex-1 z-10">
                <div class="w-6 h-6 bg-white -ml-4 rounded-full border-2 border-secondary">
                </div>
            </div>
        
        
            <div class="w-full align-center items-center align-middle content-center flex">
                <div class="w-full items-center align-middle align-center flex-1">
                     <div class="bg-white border-2 -ml-2 rounded-full border-secondary py-xs w-full"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
    
            <div class="flex-1 z-10">
                <div class="w-6 h-6 bg-white border-2 border-secondary -ml-4 rounded-full">
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default DifficultyBar
```

Comment: You need to check for the difficulty level and based on that you swap the class: bg-white for bg-secondary in each circles div.

Comment: Thanks for your response.Could you please show me some code logic so that, I can get a better idea of How to implement it?